# What blocks incoming connection on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I have reduced setup to just 2 computers connected via switch with fixed IP addresses.

PC-A is able to connect to or ping PC-B

PC-B is not able to connect to or ping PC-A

Windows firewall is disabled on both PCs.

How do I find out what program is blocking incoming connections to PC-A? Because there is no HW that will block connections, there must be some software blocking that, but I have no clue how to find it.

Thanks

Comment: I'd try enabling Windows firewall and setting a rule to allow ICMP. I've seen where Windows Firewall still blocks traffic even though it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Are these clean Windows install, or are they company image? Other common software that blocks traffic include AV, HIP etc. Disable them - or go into safe mode and try, then re-enable one by one to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your network typ in the network settings.

   Choose Start→Control Panel and, under the Network and Internet heading, click the   View Network Status and Tasks link. This should not be set to Public Network.
   Create a Home Network on both PCs.
2. Check any third party security software like antivirus with and additional firewall that could block incoming connections.
3. Check Network discoverability

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/enable-disable-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7